# Crazy Access Violation in C++ Builder 6

Tags: c++builder, access-violation

I have the following code, and for the life of me, I cannot understand why there would be an Access Violation exception? I even deleted all the OBJs, TDS etc files and put it into a new project, still the Access Violation occurs.

Essentially, this code displays a TListView in a TFrame and is to show the various current times around the world for different time zones.

Note: The code is in C++ Builder 6.

Can someone help?

**BLOODY-HELL-UPDATE**:
Solved. I should not add items to TListView in the TFrame constructor. DUMB  DUMB  DUMB.

**MAJOR UPDATE**:
It seems that when the UpdateTimes() is called via the timer, the "li->Deleting" property is TRUE. When called outside the timer, it is FALSE. Now why would "li->Deleting" be set to 'true' because it is called from the timer? If i do:

```
if(li->Deleting == false)
{
  li->Caption = "abcd";
}
```

It doesnt enter the if(), when UpdateTimes() is called from the timer...... argggggh!!!

**UPDATE:** It seems like if I call UpdateTimes() outside of the TTimer, it works fine. But when called from the timer, it throws the Access Violation. What gives?

Header File:

```
#ifndef CurrentTimes_FrameH
#define CurrentTimes_FrameH
#include <Classes.hpp>
#include <Controls.hpp>
#include <StdCtrls.hpp>
#include <Forms.hpp>
#include <ExtCtrls.hpp>
#include <ComCtrls.hpp>
#include <list>
using namespace std;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct LOCATIONTIMEINFORMATION
{
  AnsiString TimeZoneName;
  AnsiString PlaceName;
  int    UtcOffsetMinutes;
  TListItem* ListItem;
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TCurrentTimesFrame : public TFrame
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
    TTimer *Timer;
    TListView *ListView;
    void __fastcall TimerTimer(TObject *Sender);
private:    // User declarations
public:     // User declarations
    __fastcall TCurrentTimesFrame(TComponent* Owner);
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//User Code
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
private:
    list<LOCATIONTIMEINFORMATION>   FTimeInformation;
  typedef list<LOCATIONTIMEINFORMATION>::iterator LocationTimeInformationItr;
public:
  void AddTimeInformation(LOCATIONTIMEINFORMATION lti);
  void UpdateTimes();
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

CPP File:

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "CurrentTimes_Frame.h"
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TCurrentTimesFrame::TCurrentTimesFrame(TComponent* Owner): TFrame(Owner)
{
  Timer->Enabled = false;
  <strike>{
    LOCATIONTIMEINFORMATION lti;
    lti.TimeZoneName = "UTC";
    lti.PlaceName = "Near Greenwich, England";
    lti.UtcOffsetMinutes = 0;
    AddTimeInformation(lti);
  }</strike>
  //UPADTED: Don't add TListItem from constructor 
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void TCurrentTimesFrame::AddTimeInformation(LOCATIONTIMEINFORMATION lti)
{
  TListItem* li = ListView->Items->Add();
  li->Caption = lti.TimeZoneName;
  li->SubItems->Add(lti.PlaceName);
  li->SubItems->Add(lti.UtcOffsetMinutes);
  li->SubItems->Add("<time will come here>");
  lti.ListItem = li;
  ShowMessage(AnsiString(lti.ListItem->ClassName())); //Correctly shows "TListItem"
  FTimeInformation.push_back(lti);

  {
  LOCATIONTIMEINFORMATION temp = FTimeInformation.front();
  ShowMessage(AnsiString(temp.ListItem->ClassName())); //Correctly shows "TListItem"
  }
  Timer->Enabled = true;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TCurrentTimesFrame::TimerTimer(TObject *Sender)
{
    UpdateTimes();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void TCurrentTimesFrame::UpdateTimes()
{
  Timer->Enabled = false;
  TListItem* li;
  for(LocationTimeInformationItr itr=FTimeInformation.begin();itr!=FTimeInformation.end();itr++)
  {
    li = itr->ListItem;

    ShowMessage(AnsiString(li->ClassName())); //Access Violation:
    /*
    ShowMessage() above shows:

    ---------------------------
    Debugger Exception Notification
    ---------------------------
    Project XX.exe raised exception class EAccessViolation with message 'Access violation at address 4000567D in module 'rtl60.bpl'. Read of address 00000000'. Process stopped. Use Step or Run to continue.
    ---------------------------
    OK   Help
    ---------------------------
    */
  }
  Timer->Enabled = true;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**UPDATE** A sample code demo'ing that list takes items as copy, not reference.
(As far as I can see, please correct me if im making some mistake in the code below)

@Craig Young:

I'm confused... I thought structs would be added to the list as a **copy** not as a reference?
Please take a look at the code below, it seems that a copy is being made? Or am I missing something rudimentary? Or a coding mistake below??

```
void PopulateData()
{
    AnsiString DebugText;
    list<LOCATIONTIMEINFORMATION> Data;

  LOCATIONTIMEINFORMATION OnStack;

  //Prints "junk"
  DebugText.sprintf("%s,%s,%d,%d",OnStack.TimeZoneName,OnStack.PlaceName,OnStack.UtcOffsetMinutes,(int)OnStack.ListItem);

    OnStack.TimeZoneName = "UTC";
    OnStack.PlaceName = "Near Greenwich, England";
    OnStack.UtcOffsetMinutes = 10;
    OnStack.ListItem = (TListItem*)20;

  //OnStack:
  DebugText.sprintf("%s,%s,%d,%d",OnStack.TimeZoneName,OnStack.PlaceName,OnStack.UtcOffsetMinutes,(int)OnStack.ListItem);
  //Add data to list
    Data.push_back(OnStack);

  //Get struct from list
  LOCATIONTIMEINFORMATION InList = Data.front();

  //OnStack:
  DebugText.sprintf("%s,%s,%d,%d",OnStack.TimeZoneName,OnStack.PlaceName,OnStack.UtcOffsetMinutes,(int)OnStack.ListItem);
  //InList:
  DebugText.sprintf("%s,%s,%d,%d",InList.TimeZoneName,InList.PlaceName,InList.UtcOffsetMinutes,(int)InList.ListItem);

  //Change OnStack
    OnStack.TimeZoneName = "NONE";
    OnStack.PlaceName = "USA";
    OnStack.UtcOffsetMinutes = 50;
    OnStack.ListItem = (TListItem*)90;

  //OnStack:
  DebugText.sprintf("%s,%s,%d,%d",OnStack.TimeZoneName,OnStack.PlaceName,OnStack.UtcOffsetMinutes,(int)OnStack.ListItem);
  //InList:
  DebugText.sprintf("%s,%s,%d,%d",InList.TimeZoneName,InList.PlaceName,InList.UtcOffsetMinutes,(int)InList.ListItem);

  //Change InList:
    InList.TimeZoneName = "SOME";
    InList.PlaceName = "BRAZIL";
    InList.UtcOffsetMinutes = 66;
    InList.ListItem = (TListItem*)88;

  //OnStack:
  DebugText.sprintf("%s,%s,%d,%d",OnStack.TimeZoneName,OnStack.PlaceName,OnStack.UtcOffsetMinutes,(int)OnStack.ListItem);
  //InList:
  DebugText.sprintf("%s,%s,%d,%d",InList.TimeZoneName,InList.PlaceName,InList.UtcOffsetMinutes,(int)InList.ListItem);
}
```

Comment: SOLVED. OK. What I learnt is that, DONT add items to TListView in the constructor. How DUMB.

Comment: Not quite; your 'solution' may have changed something else, but creating TListItems in the constructor should not inherently cause problems. Please check out my detailed answer.

Comment: My mistake. I tend to have more of a Delphi mindset; and without an STL, our TList will always hold items by reference  unless a special effort is made otherwise. However, I tested your original code, and it works perfectly - so I think your mistake is elsewhere. Please post how you are using the frame.

Comment: Craig, I think you are right. The problem appears to be that the Deletion event of the listview gets called when the LOCATIONTIMEINFORMATION goes out of scope. I have no idea why that should happen. But of late, the error does not seem to be occuring anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **EDIT**: My answer is incorrect, I've decided to leave it in place because it is worthwhile bearing in mind that if your collection (list) holds elements by reference, this is a very real possibility for 'strange access violations'. The symptoms described would correlate perfectly had it not been for the STL list keeping a copy of the elements.

Hi Liao,

You wrote: "**BLOODY-HELL-UPDATE**: Solved. I should not add items to TListView in the TFrame constructor."

I'm going to disagree with you; you **have not** solved it. While not necessarily a good idea (in terms of design), adding items to TListView in the TFrame constructor should not cause access violations.

> **EDIT**: Despite my answer below being incorrect, I still disagree with Liao's 'BLOODY-HELL-UPDATE'. Adding items to TListView in the TFrame constructor **should not** cause access violations. In fact I took the original code and tested it in CPBB 2009, and it worked perfectly. This suggests that the error may have been in how the frame was used; or some other aspect of the code that was not demonstrated.

The problem is with the following line in the constructor:

```
LOCATIONTIMEINFORMATION lti;
```

- This allocates lti on the stack.
- You then add lti to a list; or more correctly: *you add a **reference** to lti to the list*.
- When your constructor goes out of scope, so does lti; and that memory can be reused by any other part of your application.
- Later when your timer attempts the update, the reference in FTimeInformation is still there.
- You use this reference to lookup where lti **was**.
- If that section of memory has been changed by any other part of your application, then `ltr->ListItem` no longer references the TListItem that was created in the constructor. Instead it references some other part of memory that it tries to use as if it were a TListItem. Therefore you experience 'strange' problems such as:

  - li->Deleting == false
  - li->ClassName causing an access violation.

NOTE: Whether or not you actually get an access violation usually depends a bit on luck: Consider yourself **lucky** if you **do** get the access violation; the other option is usually 'inexplicable' erratic behaviour.

Try modifying your constructor as follows, it should fix the access violation. NOTE: lti is now dynamically allocated, you'll have to decide when to free it, otherwise you'll have a memory leak ;)

```
LOCATIONTIMEINFORMATION* lti = new LOCATIONTIMEINFORMATION;
lti->TimeZoneName = "UTC";
lti->PlaceName = "Near Greenwich, England";
lti->UtcOffsetMinutes = 0;
AddTimeInformation(*lti);
```

Comment: You said that "You then add lti to a list; or more correctly: you add a reference to lti to the list." But I'm not sure thats correct..

I added a code sample at the end of the question (it would not fit in the comment which is max 600 chars). The code sample seems to show that list.push_back adds a *copy* of the struct, not a reference. Could you run that and see?

Comment: -10 for incorrect diagnosis. push_back() in (at least) a STL list, adds a *copy*, not a *reference* of the struct. Only while *accessing* the STL list items, it does return references.

Comment: You're right; my answer is incorrect. In fact I've plugged your original code into CPPB 2009, dropped the frame on a form, and it worked perfectly. This suggests that your error was not in the code you demonstrated, but perhaps in how you're using the frame?

Answer (score 0):

I can't actually see any problem with the code.

Try printing the TimeZoneName or PlaceName from your iterator, rather than li->ClassName(), to make sure you haven't accidentally added something else to the list or something...

Comment: Doing
    ShowMessage(itr->PlaceName);
works.
That means that itr->ListItem is "ruined" somewhere?

Comment: So, the problem was infact my bad. Not to ever ever ever add TListItem and suchlike in the ctor.

Answer (score 0):

What values do you have in FTimeInformation? For example, is li == NULL?

---

If we can assume that the access violation occurs the first time through the loop, and li points to a valid TListItem then perhaps we should split the three statements on the line over three lines. Something like this:

```
const char* className = li->ClassName();
AnsiString  ansiString(className);
ShowMessage(ansiString);
```

If the access violation doesn't happen on the first line this will tell us something interesting.

Comment: No luck with that. See my "UPDATE:" in the question. Basically, the access violation is only occuring when UpdateTimes() is called from within the timer.

Comment: Does the timer use a separate thread? If it does, then access to shared values should be made in a thread-safe way, because otherwise there is no guarantee that changes made in one thread are visible to another.

Comment: No separate thread.. please see new 2nd "UPDATE:" in my question

Comment: Just to expand on the solution in your third update, lti is created on the stack in the scope of the constructor, so it goes out of scope when the constructor returns. lti is passed by value into AddTimeInformation(...), which creates the copy that is added to the list by reference with push_back(const T&). At the end of AddTimeInformation(...), the copy goes out of scope, leaving a reference to reclaimed memory in the list.